# Unnesting string of json arrays in Athena

Tags: sql, hive, amazon-athena

I'm using Athena to read in data from some json objects in s3. I've created the table with

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "database".table_name (
  `_1` array < varchar(1000) >
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'

LOCATION 's3://bucket/folder/'
```

The raw data looks like:

```
{
  "_1": [
    {
      "Runner Name": 36492083,
      "Market": "4m2f Hcap Chs",
      "Last Matched Price": 8.8,
      "Available to Back": [
        [
          8.6,
          501.37
        ],
        [
          8.4,
          269.38
        ],
        [
          8.2,
          232.25
        ]
      ],
      "Available to Lay": [
        [
          8.8,
          92.55
        ],
        [
          9,
          309.35
        ],
        [
          9.2,
          150.17
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "Runner Name": 17209413,
      "Market": "4m2f Hcap Chs",
      "Last Matched Price": 9,
      "Available to Back": [
        [
          9,
          450.12
        ],
        [
          8.8,
          229.87
        ],
        [
          8.6,
          362.53
        ]
      ],
      "Available to Lay": [
        [
          9.2,
          37.18
        ],
        [
          9.4,
          272.04
        ],
        [
          9.6,
          157.9
        ]
      ]
    },...
```

I'm trying to unnest the data contained in each row, but when I run the query

```
with odds_file as (
    select cast(json_parse("_1"[1]) as array(varchar)) as data

    from database.table_name

    limit 10
)
SELECT * FROM odds_file
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(data) as t(data)

;
```

I'm getting the error message: INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast to array(varchar). Unexpected token when cast to varchar: { [{"Runner Name": 42532308, "Market": "2m3f Nov Hrd", "Last Matched Price": 1.25, "Available to Back": [[1.25, 19.08], [1.24, 17.98], [1.23, 90.17]], "Available to Lay": [[1.26, 16.29], [1.27, 15.56], [1.28, 19.09]]}, {"Runner Name": 49854146, "Market": "2m3f Nov Hrd", "Last Matched Price": 7.8, "Available to Back": [[7.4, 11.14], [6.6, 14.88], [5.2, 12.67]], "Available to Lay": [[8.8, 10.2], [9.2, 20.0], [17.0, 10.25]]}, {"Runner Name": 43045564, "Market": "2m3f Nov Hrd", "Last Matched Price": 28.0, "Available to Back": [[23.0, 10.49], [16.0, 20.51], [11.0, 24.0]], "Available to Lay": [[55.0, 12.97], [1000.0, 3.33]]}, {"Runner Name": 50369891, "Market": "2m3f Nov Hrd", "Last Matched Price": 38.0, "Available to Back": [[16.0, 29.59], [11.0, 24.0], [6.2, 46.15]], "Available to Lay": [[110.0, 11.53], [350.0, 11.0], [990.0, 2.88]]}, {"Runner Name": 52027534, "Market": "2m3f Nov Hrd", "Last Matched Price": 55.0, "Available to Back": [[17.0, 10.74], [16.0, 20.0], [11.0, 24.0]], "Available to